# how to remove the buttons in angular js confirm dialog popup?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web, mean-stack, mddialog

I want to remove the buttons in angular material dialog box.

I can't hide using css and jquery because class name is generated by angular js which will hide the buttons in other dialog popups also.

code attached

```js
angular.module('app', ['angular.filter', 'ngMaterial', 'ngMessages'] )
.run(function($rootScope,$mdDialog) {
      $rootScope.showConfirm = function(ev) {
      var confirm = $mdDialog.confirm()
          .title('processing payment')
          .textContent('Please Wait...  we are processing your payment.')
          .ariaLabel('')
          .targetEvent(ev)
          .ok('Conform')
          .cancel('Dont cancel');
          $mdDialog.show(confirm).then(function() {
      $rootScope.status = '';
      }, function() {
      $rootScope.status = '';
      });
      };
    })
```

```html
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-filter/0.5.8/angular-filter.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-messages.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.gitcdn.link/cdn/angular/bower-material/v1.1.5/angular-material.js"></script>
  
  <body>
<img src="images/bg-02.jpg" class="z-index-4" />



<div ng-app="app">
  <div class="container">
<a ng-click="showConfirm($event)" href="javascript:void()">open dialog</a>

</div>
```

Comment: Why do you want to remove buttons in confirm dialog? you need at least 1 button to confirm

Comment: I'm developing a food ordering KIOSK. After customer clicks the pay button they have to wait idle untill the admin receives cash and redirects the customer to thank you page.

Comment: I needed this exact thing to show an alert that a users account was disabled. Then to prevent them from using the app without contacting customer support. I used a custom md-dialog template with no okay or cancel buttons, then set the clickOutsideToClose and escapeToClose to false. Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

Angular Material has a set of Dialogs that you can use, `cofirm dialog` is one of those, but if you don't need confirm or cancel button, you can use `alert dialog`. As @Maxim Shoustin says, you need at least one button, but you can try to leave the `ok(' ')` with empty string.

[Angular Material Modals](http://Maxim%20Shoustin)

```
$mdDialog.show(
      $mdDialog.alert()
        .parent(angular.element(document.querySelector('#yourDialogEL')))
        .clickOutsideToClose(true)
        .title('Dialog TItle')
        .textContent('Content')
        .ariaLabel('aria labels')
        .ok('Got it!')
        .targetEvent(ev)
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend create your own custom Dialog, where you will have the requested control.